# How to measure the speed in a catalized reaction?

Tags: reaction-control

What is cheaper?

- Set up a constant time of reaction and measure the concentration of the products or;
- Set up a constant quantity of reactants and, with an indicator, measure the time until the reaction stops.

If you know another protocol, Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on scenario.

If time is cheap, while measurement is expensive ( e.g.high fixed price for each value ), then constant time method is probably cheaper.

If time is expensive, while measurement cheap ( e.g. continuos measurement ), the constant products method may be cheaper.